# A normed linear space is separable if and only if it has a denumerable dense subset.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

> A normed linear space $X$ is separable if and only if it has a denumerable
>   dense subset.

*Proof*: Suppose $X$ is separable. Then $X$ has a countable dense subset, say $D$. If $D$ is denumerable, there is nothing to prove. If $D$ is finite, define $D':=D\cup\{q_iy \mid q_i\in\mathbb Q\}$, where $y$ is some fixed element in $D$. Then $D'$ is a denumerable dense subset.

Conversely, if $X$ has a denumerable dense subset, then $X$ is separable by definition. $\blacksquare$

---

Is the above proof correct? It seems so simple. Is there anything that I'm overlooking?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake is you forgot to say $y \neq 0$. (If $X=\{0\}$  then the result is false).